# Reinstalling Mysql On Ubuntu 10.10(Stuck with bad repositories)

Tags: mysql, apt

I recently configured NDB-cluster with MySQL and MySQL just crashed ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

tried re-installing MySQL-server as it wasn't there anymore but failed, with ubuntu missing repository entries. I removed MySQL from my system completely.

Now the main issues

1. apt-get install wont show any MySQL package,
2. apt-get update still wont add any MySQL repository
3. packages in MySQL site are rpm not .deb I've been going round and round with these commands for a day or two now all in vain

No idea what I'm missing.